# After spring-boot upgrade from 1.5.6.RELEASE to 2.2.4.RELEASE spring requesting a JdbcTemplate bean to be defined to Autowire JdbcTemplate

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

```
@Autowired
JdbcTemplate template;
```

The above code is not working and after the spring-boot-2.2.4 upgrade. It requesting a bean to be defined. But the same code worked perfectly without defining any bean for JdbcTemplate.

**Below solution which worked for me:**

After adding below code my code works fine.

```
@Bean
    @RefreshScope
    public JdbcTemplate template() {
        return new JdbcTemplate(this.dataSource());
    }
```

Can someone please tell me why we need explicit bean to be defined for JdbcTemplate and not in previous version of spring?

*Note: I have update spring-jpa, spring-security and other dependencies as part of the spring upgrade*

Comment: Can you show your pom.xml

Comment: Also share the Datasource full qualified name